# Accesse violation at address в Delphi dll

Tags: delphi

Всем привет. Я уже не знаю, как избавиться от этой ошибки ...

Ошибка периодически вылезает на втором шаге

> Step2 Accesse violation at address 0AC95985 in module … Read of
>   address FFFFFFFC, high(a)=31

```
Library hash_sha256;

{ Important note about DLL memory management: ShareMem must be the
  first unit in your library's USES clause AND your project's (select
  Project-View Source) USES clause if your DLL exports any procedures or
  functions that pass strings as parameters or function results. This
  applies to all strings passed to and from your DLL--even those that
  are nested in records and classes. ShareMem is the interface unit to
  the BORLNDMM.DLL shared memory manager, which must be deployed along
  with your DLL. To avoid using BORLNDMM.DLL, pass string information
  using PChar or ShortString parameters. }

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Hash,
  Vcl.Dialogs;

{$R *.res}

function MyHash(AKey, AData: PAnsiChar): Pchar; stdcall;
var
  a: TArray<byte>;
  i: integer;
  s: ShortString;
begin
  try
    s:='';
    Result:='';

    try
      a:=THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes(String(AData), String(AKey));
    except
      on E : Exception do
         ShowMessage('Step1'+E.Message);
    end;


    try
      for i:=0 to high(a) do
        s:=s+PChar(inttohex(a[i],2));
    except
      on E : Exception do
        ShowMessage('Step2 '+E.Message+', high(a)='+IntToStr(high(a)));
    end;

    try
      Result:=Pchar(s+'');
    except
      on E : Exception do
        ShowMessage('Step3'+E.Message);
    end;

  except
    on E : Exception do
      begin
        Result:=Pchar(AnsiString(E.Message));
      end;
  end;
end;

exports MyHash name 'hash_sha256';

begin
end.
```

Нюанс ещё состоит в том, что библиотека пишется на 10 delphi (delphi XE 10 ), а программа, которая её использует - на старенькой Delphi7 ... Видимо поэтому, и вариант с использованием AnsiString c BORLNDMM.DLL и ShareMem приводил постоянно к Accesse violation но только уже при подключении к библиотеке.

Comment: one more again :) строки нумеруются с 1. Это унаследовано от паскаля. И цикл нужно сделать `for i:=1 to Length(a)`. Для 100% совместимости нужно указывать везде PAnsiChar, а не PChar.

Comment: @kami Так `а` же не строка.

Comment: @kami Первоначально, я тоже на это грешил ... Но когда заменил c i:=0 на i:=1, то результат выполнения функции стал короче на один символ ... ( на первый символ )

Comment: String(AData), String(AKey) - я бы попробовал записать AData и AKey - каждую в переменную строкого типа. Ну и также выделить память под "a" при помощи setlength. Это танцы с бубном конечно, но повысит управляемость памятью.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пункт 0.

```
function MyHash(AKey, AData: PAnsiChar): Pchar; stdcall;
```

Почему в декларации функции у Вас смешаны два разных `PChar`'a? Если один из модулей  компилируется в Delphi 7, ставьте везде `PAnsiChar`.

Пункт 1.

Почему вдруг используется `ShortString`?

Пункт 2.

Попробуйте ответить на такой вопрос - кто (какой модуль) распределяет и освобождает память, указатель на которую Вы возвращаете, и в какие моменты это (распределение и освобождение) происходит.

Вы возвращаете указатель на данные строки, которая является локальной (сгенеренной компилятором) переменной внутри Вашей функции. Память под эту строку освобождается в момент выхода из функции. Если Вам повезет, и этот кусок памяти останется нетронутым, вызывающий код может успеть скопировать оттуда данные. А может и не успеть.

Вам следует распределять буфер под результат на стороне вызывающего кода и подавать указатель на этот буфер и размер буфера третьим и четвертым параметрами. Возвращать Ваша функция должна требуемый размер буфера. Если поданный буфер меньше требуемого - ничего в него не писать.

Пункт 3.

Зачем эти танцы с кастами `s:=s+PChar(inttohex(a[i],2));`?

Comment: По поводу 0 пункта - справедливо, исправил ), Пункт 1 - Если использовать обычный String, то в основную программу, откуда вызывается библиотека вместо строки передается 1 символ.По поводу пункта 2 - исправил. Пункт 3 - вылезали предупреждения Implicit string cast from 'ShortString' to 'string'

Comment: @user6802100 Добавьте значение `i` к сообщению об ошибке, чтобы выяснить, на какой итерации она происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Очень важно не смешивать `PChar` и `PAnsiChar` в коде. Использовать же `PChar` в API dll вообще нельзя, потому что это алиас и в зависимости от версии Delphi этот тип равен либо `PAnsiChar`, либо `PWideChar`.

Далее, стоит придерживаться правила: *"Кто выделяет память, тот её и освобождает"*, особенно, при написании dll. Вы должны чётко представлять, в какой момент и кем память выделяется и когда и кем освобождается. Delphi от нас прячет всю рутину по управлению памятью при работе со строками, но при передачи значений из/в dll это только вредит, особенно новичкам.

Если ваша функция выделяет память под строку для возвращения результата, то у вас в API должна быть предусмотрена доп. функция, для освобождения этой памяти. И вы должны позаботиться, чтобы Delphi не уничтожила эту строку автоматически, при выходе из функции.

Есть и другой вариант - вызывающая функция должна выделить буфер достаточного размера под результат и передать в вашу функцию указатель на него и размер буфера.

Поскольку длина результирующей строки с SHA256 заранее известна (64 символа), то можно в документации объявить о соглашении, что буфер должен быть не менее 64-х байт:

```
const
  c_SHA256_StrLen = 64;

procedure MyHash(const AKey, AData: PAnsiChar; const AHash: PAnsiChar); stdcall;
var
  I: Integer;
  VByteStr: AnsiString;
  VKey, VData, VHash: TBytes;
begin
  if System.AnsiStrings.StrLen(AHash) >= c_SHA256_StrLen then begin
    VKey := BytesOf(AKey, System.AnsiStrings.StrLen(AKey));
    VData := BytesOf(AData, System.AnsiStrings.StrLen(AData));
    VHash := THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes(VData, VKey);
    for I := Low(VHash) to High(VHash) do begin
      VByteStr := VByteStr + AnsiString(LowerCase(IntToHex(VHash[I], 2)));
    end;
    System.AnsiStrings.StrLCopy(AHash, PAnsiChar(VByteStr), c_SHA256_StrLen)
  end;
end;
```

Для удобства вызова этой функции из dll, в приложении можно написать обёртку:

```
function CalcSHA256(const AKey, AData: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var
  VHash: PAnsiChar;
  VHashLen: Integer;
begin
  VHashLen := c_SHA256_StrLen;
  VHash := AllocMem(VHashLen + 1); // +1 для завершающего нуля
  try
    FillChar(VHash^, VHashLen, '0');
    MyHash(PAnsiChar(AKey), PAnsiChar(AData), VHash);
    Result := AnsiString(VHash);
  finally
    FreeMem(VHash);
  end;
end;
```

Тест:

```
CalcSHA256('key', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
// f7bc83f430538424b13298e6aa6fb143ef4d59a14946175997479dbc2d1a3cd8
```

Обратите внимание, что в приложении должна выделяться память с запасом на 1 байт, для хранения завершающего нуля. И, соответственно, этот нулевой символ должен быть туда записан, что достигается использованием функции `AllocMem`, которая выделяет и забивает нулями выделенную память.